# Store value from a whileloop into an array then sum the array

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to store an unknown amount of data into an array, while using a forloop to get data! My task is to find and sum all the numbers form 1 to 1000 that can be divided be 3 and 5.

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 1001; i++)

        if (i%3==0)
        {
            if (i%5==0)
            {

      //this doesn't work, have tried to convert it to string, didn't work either
               int[] array = { i };

         //trying to loop the values                    
         for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; i++)
               {

               //how can I loop this so I dont have to write it all out?

                   int sum1 = array[j]


               }

            }
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: try List<int> instead of array, array will have to be defined with a specific size before using it.

Comment: You need to explain yourself well.

Comment: Why are u storing data in array? You can just accumulate data in one variable.

Comment: Hi Lindgreen, as you are new to SO, please be aware, that the professionals giving answers here, are hungry for reputation points. Please go through the answers and vote them up if they are helpful. If one of them helped you to solve your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer, This will show to others, that this question is solved. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Just because computers can perform repetitive task well doesn't mean you ignore Mathematics. If I got it right, you are trying to find the sum of all the numbers less than 1000 which are divisible by both 3 and 5. So that boils down to all the multiples of 15. Now if you take the floor of 1000/15, you get the the last multiple, which in this case is 66. So, you have to sum the series:

```
15, 15*2, 15*3,...15*66
    =15*(1+2+3+..+66)   [15*sum of first 66 positive natural numbers]
    =15*66*67/2
```

So generalizing, finding sum of all numbers less than **a** and divisible by **b** is given by:

```
limit = floor(a/b);
sum = b*limit*(limit+1)/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var ListOfInts=new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i < 1001; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
        ListOfInts.Add(i);
}
var result = ListOfInts.Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this code does what you want:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> li = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) 
            {
                if (i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0) 
                {
                    li.Add(i);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("sum is " + li.Sum());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The number devides by 3 and 5 means it devides by 15. So you can start iterating from 15 and incrementing by 15 to skip some iterations:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 15; i <= 1000; i += 15)
    sum += i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! Alot of good answers, i'm still trying to understand some of them but thanks :)

How come that

```
 List<int> li = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) 
        {
            if (i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0) 
            {
                li.Add(i);
            }
        }
        Console.Write("sum is " + li.Sum());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

give me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UffEd.png)
while the code down under

```
var ListofInts = new List<int>();

        for (int i  = 0; i < 1001; i++)
        {
            if (i%3==0 && i%5==0)
            {
                ListofInts.Add(i);

                var result = ListofInts.Sum();

                Console.Write(result + ", ");
            }

        }
```

gives me [this?](https://i.gyazo.com/92008bae5b7b8efb78b158ff11e5fe3d.png)